# Can't see footer on website and cannot scroll to see

Tags: scroll, footer

I have a fixed footer on my site here:  http://starprovisions.com/dev/bacchanalia.html  On my 1360x768 screen I can only see the top of the footer and when I try to scroll it either does not scroll or if it does, the footer does not scroll with the whole site, staying below the content. Is there a way to fix this so that the whole webpage scrolls up and down so we can see the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set its position to relative, so it will be below your main content. This way it will allow you to scroll down

```
#footer {
    height: 75px;
    background: 
    white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative; /*Added this*/
    width: 100%;
 }
```

And also for your html css, you should remove the

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

If you dont want to constantly show the scrollbar on the side of the window.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It is sitting below the content now and allowing me to scroll to see it, but it is not staying put when I scroll left to right. I guess that is why I wanted it fixed positioned. Is there a way to get it to sit relative (below) the content, allow for the whole web page to scroll up and down but also stay right in the center of the screen and not move when you scroll left to right? Like this site:  http://www.woodberrykitchen.com/

Comment: The woodberrykitchen site the footer stays in a constant position, and the images above are just sliding into position. This is a different way of what you want to achieve. I think if you want your way to work, you would have to make sure your footer shifts over depeding on the scrollbar position.

Comment: I basically just always want the footer to remain centered in the middle of the screen (but below the main content of the site) no matter what "panel" you are viewing within the horizontal scroll. Is there some java script or something I can code in that you could point me to, to make sure the footer shifts over depending on the scrollbar position?